# WPF ListView Selecting Multiple List View Items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, select

I am figuring out a way to Select Multiple items in list view and deleting them on a certain action.
What I can't figure out is, how should I have these multiple items selected? I would think there is a list that I would need to add them all into, but what's the best way to approach this situation, do you have any ideas?
Thanks!
-Kevin

Answer (score 27):

Set [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionmode.aspx) to `Multiple` or `Extended` and iterate through the[`SelectedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx) in your `ListView`.

Comment: Worth noting that `SelectionMode.Multiple` does not include the ability to use Shift+Click to select consecutive items or Ctrl+A to select all. Seems like a bug/oversight.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest do not use the `SelectedItems` property of `ListView`, instead bind the `Selected` property of the single `ListViewItem`, to a corresponding `ViewModel` class. After this, the only thing you need to do is to find all `ViewModel` object that have bound the `Selected` property TRUE, remove them from model collection (if you do remove) and refresh UI. If the collection is `ObservableCollection`, the UI will be refreshed automatically.
Good Luck.

Comment: Could you please provide any reasons why you should not use the `SelectedItems` property?

Comment: because it makes design more complicated and that may lead to bugs. If you have a Selected Property on each object that is in the ItemsSource you can bind each item very easily like this:                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                    </Style>

Comment: @NomanKhan Should be ListViewItem not ListBoxItem; also no need for BasedOn I think... But good comment, helped me!

Answer (score 11):

Arcturus answer is good if you're not using MVVM. But if you do and your ItemsSource is binded to some ObservableCollection of objects in your ViewModel, I would recommend Tigran answer, with Noman Khan clarification.

This is how it would look like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeListViewList}">
    <ListView.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding SomeItemSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
       </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    ...
</ListView>
```

In View Model you would have object: `public ObservableCollection<SomeItem> SomeListViewList{ get; set; }`

SomeItem Class would include a Selected property:

```
public class SomeItem
{
    public string SomeItemName { get; set; }

    public string SomeItemNum { get; set; }

    public bool SomeItemSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could iterate/run over the list and get the ones that are selected:

```
foreach (var item in SomeListViewList)
   if (item.SomeItemSelected)
      // do something
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do one of the following...

`ListView.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended` in code-behind or

`<ListView SelectionMode="Extended"></ListView>` in XAML

you also have 'multiple' selectionMode yet you could rather go for 'extended' which allows the user to select multiple items only using shift modifier.

For deleting the items selected you could use the ListView.SelectedItems Propery as follows

```
while( myListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 )
{
    myListView.Items.Remove(list.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

[or you could use the SelectedIndices property]

Hope this will avoid the issue you encountered :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Get success also WPF listview by writing

```
while (lvJournalDetails.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    lvJournalDetails.Items.Remove(lvJournalDetails.SelectedItem);
}
```