# How to remove anchorItem in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, selection

I have a ListView to which item source is given from the viewModel. On a button click the selected items will be changed. Now the problem is, the previous item of Listview is displaying as selected. When I observed, the selected item is set to the expected value but the anchor item is having previously selected Item. I am suspecting that due to the anchor Item the item is displaying as selected.

[image]

In the above screenshot,
test t2 is currently selected one
Test t3 is the anchor item, which I have selected previously.

here is my listView

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="AllUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Users}}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Cursor="Hand" AllowDrop="False" ForceCursor="True" MouseLeftButtonUp="OnUsersSelected"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                    
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            // Some code
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Can someone help me to fix this, please.

Comment: Do you mean that item is focused? Do you have focused style in the datatemplate?  You can override item template and bind select stylings.

Comment: Yes @IevgenNaida

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146269/change-wpf-datatemplate-for-listbox-item-if-selected

Comment: If you don't need some functionally from the item template: focused, selected. You can override item template and turn off those features

Comment: Thanks, @Ievgen Naida, I will try this approach.

Comment: No Luck @IevgenNaida, still the view is the same as in the screenshot. Am I missing anything, I am actually looking for-> If any other item is selected, the only currently selected item should be highlighted.

Comment: But solution is still the same. You should override not a data template but a style and disable default focus and selection styling. also you can control completely styling of selected items https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282138/wpf-listview-selecting-multiple-list-view-items